# In Mogworld, what is the nature of the relationship between Mr. Wonderful and Bowg?

Tags: mogworld

In Mogworld, the assassin team of Mr. Wonderful and Bowg seem to have a pretty odd relationship.  Mr. Wonderful appears to be a normal - albeit psychopathic - fellow, while Bowg comes across as almost robotic.  More than that, on the couple of occasions when Mr. Wonderful starts to waver from his path, Bowg quickly brings him back in line with simple gestures or words that suggest some kind of mind-controlling effect.  Yet, by the end of the book, Croshaw has revealed nothing unnatural about their relationship and even gives us some indication that there really isn't anything special going on there.

Did I miss some passage in the book that helps explain Bowg's apparent control over Mr. Wonderful?  Or are they perhaps an homage to some buddy cop show that I don't recognize?

Comment: Hey look, a book-club question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing in the book explicitly explains the reason(s) Mr. Wonderful obeys Bowg and the Adventuring Guild.

However, rather than some form of mind control, it is suggested that Mr. Wonderful obeys out of fear of repercussion of disobedience. This fits in with the general *modus operandi* used by the Adventuring Guild, as they typically rely on coercion, bribery, and outright threats (as seen with the King of Lolede and Baron Civious).

While not actually stated, the most plausible explanation is that Mr. Wonderful was threatened with being thrown in a prison cell where he would be unable to hurt anyone (including himself).  Murder and torture seem to be his only motivating factors, and while he is clearly unhappy about not being able to permanently kill anyone, he states repeatedly that working as pain-for-hire for the Adventurer's Guild seems to be the only option left to him.  They certainly have the means to track him down, capture him, and throw him in a prison should he try to leave (he clearly lacks the self-control to avoid leaving a wide swath of distinctively dismembered bodies wherever he goes).

Answer (score 1):

What struck me was towards the end, atop mount mirdercruel, when wonderful says "been on that twat's leash for years" after he knocks Bowg off the mountain.  Before then I'd always been under the impression Mr. wonderful was the alpha in their relationship.
To address your question, I believe that Bowg is more or less a supervisor to Wonderful, to keep him from letting his bloodlust get in the way of collecting information or whatever else is their mission at the time.  The adventurer's guild is clearly all powerful, and essentially usurped rule of law from the royalty, so wonderful likely works with them basically for lack of any other choice.  So no, I don't believe there's any kind of mind control in play.  Bowg's words simply have the power to remind Mr. wonderful of his place in the grand scheme of things when he starts to get too unhinged.

Comment: Also, for my first read through, I kept thinking that the descriptions of Bowg's behavior and patterns of speech were meant to lead us to believe he's a victim of the syndrome, so when that never came to anything I was kind of shocked.